# Power Bi - Get Web Data

Tags: web-scraping, scrape

I have to create a power bi report that takes specific data report from multiple pages.
In my scenario I selected

---

I use get data from web

**1st issue** is that the first product is coming as header

**2nd issue** is that I try to create a function that read a range of pages but it is not working.

In advanced editor

[image]

```
###

(page as text) =>

let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.sklavenitis.gr/mpiskota-sokolates-zacharodi/"&page),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".product__title *"}, {"Column2", ".price"}, {"Column3", "SPAN + DIV P"}, {"Column4", "SPAN + DIV .btn"}, {"Column5", ".list__title"}, {"Column6", ".dropdown__list P"}, {"Column7", ".dropdown__list .btn"}, {"Column8", ".list__add"}, {"Column9", ".tooltip-trigger\-\-inline P"}, {"Column10", ".tooltip-trigger\-\-inline .btn"}, {"Column11", ".price *"}, {"Column12", "DIV:nth-child(3) SPAN:nth-child(2)"}, {"Column13", ".text-minus + *"}, {"Column14", ".priceKil .deleted__price"}, {"Column15", ".hightlight"}, {"Column16", ".main-price .deleted__price"}, {"Column17", ".priceKil .deleted__price + *"}, {"Column18", ".hightlight *"}, {"Column19", ".main-price .deleted__price + *"}, {"Column20", ".gift_number"}, {"Column21", ".gift_text"}}, [RowSelector=".product"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ΙΟΝ Σοκοφρέτα Γάλακτος με Στέβια Χωρίς προσθήκη ζάχαρης 30gr", type text}, {"0,44 €/τεμ.", type text}, {"Για να προσθέσετε το προϊόν σε Λίστα πρέπει να συνδεθείτε.", type text}, {"Είσοδος", type text}, {"Προσθήκη σε…", type text}, {"Για να δημιουργήσετε νέα Λίστα πρέπει να συνδεθείτε.", type text}, {"Είσοδος_1", type text}, {"Νέα Λίστα", type text}, {"Για να προσθέσετε το προϊόν στα Αγαπημένα σας πρέπει να συνδεθείτε.", type text}, {"Είσοδος_2", type text}, {"/τεμ.", type text}, {"Column12", type text}, {"Column13", type number}, {"Column14", type number}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type number}, {"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}, {"Column19", type text}, {"Column20", type text}, {"Column21", type text}}),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Demoted Headers",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type text}, {"Column13", type any}, {"Column14", type any}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type any}, {"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}, {"Column19", type text}, {"Column20", type text}, {"Column21", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"

###
```

--- > I used extra code to change source in order to get data from all pages

[image]

you can see the header issue

and if i select page 2 to check table

[image]

```
`{Expression.Error: The column 'ΙΟΝ Σοκοφρέτα Γάλακτος με Στέβια Χωρίς προσθήκη ζάχαρης 30gr' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    ΙΟΝ Σοκοφρέτα Γάλακτος με Στέβια Χωρίς προσθήκη ζάχαρης 30gr}
`
```

I would expect to get all data from all pages where first product is the header and all the info that comes with it.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!